# Dataframe not adding up values properly (Indexing)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
df.at[0,'Initial'] = 10000
df.loc[1:99,'Initial'] = df['Initial'].shift(1) + (df['Initial'].shift(1) * df['Pct Change'])


Initial
10000.000000
10063.995538
NaN
NaN
NaN...
```

Hi Guys with this code I have created a Starting Value of 10000 and it is supposed to add the previous value + (Previous Value * Pct Change)

However it keeps producing NaN after the second line

Any advise please?

```
Initial         Pct Change
10000.000000    -0.000710
10063.995538     0.006400
NaN              0.002827
NaN              0.009148
NaN              0.000694
```

I like the 3 line in Initial to be 10063.995538 + (10063.995538*0.002827)
But it is producing NaN
I wonder if this syntax df.loc[1:99,'Initial'] is wrong?

I only can make the Initial properly populate by doing this:

```
df.at[0,'Initial'] = 10000
df.loc[1:,'Initial'] = df['Initial'].shift(1) + (df['Initial'].shift(1) * df['Pct Change'])
df.loc[2:,'Initial'] = df['Initial'].shift(1) + (df['Initial'].shift(1) * df['Pct Change'])
df.loc[3:,'Initial'] = df['Initial'].shift(1) + (df['Initial'].shift(1) * df['Pct Change'])
`....`
```

But why wouldn't df.loc[1:99,'Initial'] work?

Comment: What is the initial value of `Initial`?

Comment: Hi I used 
df.at[0,'Initial'] = 10000
I dont have any other lines with regards to Initial other than this 2 lines

Comment: From your code, I'm assuming you want to do somewhat of an iterative computation. Unfortunately, this code isn't going to get you very far, since it works on the current values in the `Initial` column, all of which happen to be `NaN` besides the first column.

Comment: Why wont this code keep adding up? Since its suppose to add the previous value + (Pct Change of Previous Value) I dont understand why it stops at the second line. The code is suppose to start with 10000 then keep adding the Pct Change to the previous value (e.g if 3rd line it should be 10063.995538 + (10063.995538 * Pct Change)

Comment: Add the `df.head(5)` and expected output so we will be clear on what you want.

Comment: Hi, added the relevant df.head(5) because the rest of the df.head() is very long.. but for the 2 lines of code the input is only Initial and Pct Change

Comment: Its hard to vectorize this kind of problems. Added Numpy Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loop, try look at `cumprod`

```
df['Initial']=np.append(10000,df.iloc[1:,].PctChange.add(1).cumprod().values*10000)
df
Out[261]: 
   PctChange       Initial
0  -0.000710  10000.000000
1   0.006400  10064.000000
2   0.002827  10092.450928
3   0.009148  10184.776669
4   0.000694  10191.844904
```

Comment: Awesome. Really Nice. *10000 took me a while to understand. Thats why I added numpy tag. Numpy usually wins

Comment: @Bharathshetty just a multi ...~ :)

Comment: Usually I use *10000 on concat to extend the dataframe. Thats why it took me some time. Taking common from both the ends multiplying at the end. I really appreciate your math skills :)

Comment: I tried to test the speed for both Bharath and Wen answer (Wen ans gives me 2.3s while Barath 5.7s, because of the loops) Thanks guys anyway

Answer (score 1):

Its better you go for a for loop when it comes to this kind of operations i.e

```
df.loc[0,'Initial'] = 10000
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df.loc[i,'Initial'] = df.loc[i-1,'Initial'] + (df.loc[i-1,'Initial'] * df.loc[i,'Pct Change'])
```

```
       Initial  Pct Change
0  10000.000000   -0.000710
1  10064.000000    0.006400
2  10092.450928    0.002827
3  10184.776669    0.009148
4  10191.844904    0.000694
```

Comment: I was analysing it .